# Відповідник до англійського "pose estimation"

Tags: переклад, from-english, іншомовні-слова

У машинному навчанні є задача під назвою pose estimation, суть якої полягає у тому, аби для якоїсь кількості joints (у перекладі теж не впевнений) отримати координати, маючи зображення.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_pose_estimation

Варіанти які мене майже задовольняють: скелетонізація (просто і влучно, проте це більше неформальний переклад у моєму колі спілкування) або ж оцінка положення (звучить як калька, але ближче до оригіналу).

Comment: визначення пози / положення? чесно кажучи, якщо в вашому колі професіоналів так прийнято називати - то так і називайте :) наврядчи є офіційні публікації на цю тему українською мовою, тому у вас є шанс започаткувати термін

Comment: Офіційних публікацій у відомих мені наукових виданнях на цю тему українською дійсно поки не бачив.
Тож, відтепер pose estimation - скелетонізація!)

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю, що тут відповідником може бути простий переклад фрази з урахуванням того, що під оцінюванням мається на увазі *передбачення трансформації об'єкта від заданої користувачем відлікової пози* ([звідси](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_pose_estimation)). Отже дивимось у словник:

> **[estimation](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=estimation%20&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)** [ˌestɪˈmeɪʃ(ɘ)n] n
> **1.** оцінка, судження, думка, міркування;
>   **in smb’s ~** на чиюсь думку;
> **2.** повага, шана;
>   **to be held in high ~** бути дуже шанованим;
> **3.** розрахунок, підрахунок; обчислення; калькуляція, кошторис; оцінка, визначення;
>   **range ~** визначення відстані; ◊
>   **to fall in smb’s ~** впасти в чиїхсь очах.

Бачимо, що окрім запропонованого в коментарях *визначення пози* ще пасує *розрахування/обчислення пози*.

> **estimation** = [ˌɛstɪ'meɪʃn] (дія) оці́нювання/оці́нення; (результат) оці́нка
> • **adaptive ~** = адапти́вне оці́нювання
> • **analytical ~** = аналіти́чне оці́нювання
> • **asymptotic ~** = асимптоти́чне оці́нювання
> • **classic ~** = класи́чна зада́ча оці́нювання
> • **coherent ~** = когере́нтне оці́нювання
> • **confidence ~** = дові́рче оці́нювання
> • **error ~** = оці́нювання по́хибки
> • **nonparametric ~** = непараметри́чне оці́нювання
> • **quantitative ~** = кі́лькісне оці́нювання
> • **robust ~** = стійке́ оці́нювання
> • **sequential ~** = послідо́вне оці́нювання

У цьому витязі ми бачимо *error estimation* перекладене як *оцінювання похибки*, отже ми можемо перекласти і як *оцінювання пози.*